# phpMyAdmin connects only if --skip-grant-tables is active on the db server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a weird issue where I'm trying to connect phpMyAdmin to a remote server. It wasn't working at all so I was messing around with mysql in command line on the db server (no phpMyAdmin on the db). I used skip-grant tables so I could reset the root user and add myself as a user with all privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myusr'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I accidentally tried logging into PHPmyadmin at this time and it worked! Full access - can see everything in the remote DB. I know it's connected properly because changes I made in command line were showing in phpMyAdmin on the web server.

Now I stop mysqld_safe and restart the service on the db and everything dies again. I keep getting the unhelpful "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" message on phpMyAdmin without any other information. I tried tracing the connection in phpMyAdmin and setting values to test the db connection and results, but that's not working as well as I hoped.

I'll keep hacking, but I'm hoping someone has an idea what to do in this case? All the values appear to be configured correctly since it DOES connect to the db if I turn off all security. I can log into my user commandline using the same name and pass on the db server.

What else could I be missing?

EDIT: I stopped being dumb and trying to hack phpMyAdmin and made my own test php script that simply runs a mysqli_connect() attempt and returns the detailed error. I'm getting the following:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myusr'@'prodserverFQDN' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: it seems to me that you pasword might not match the expected one... did you try to change it (as root) ?

Comment: Using the password on the db server works. Ex. "mysql -u myusr -p" then type the password. Using the same login details in PHPmyadmin (and my script) results in the new error of access denied. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I kept researching while waiting for a response and I found something that works. Apparently I didn't enclose my password in quotes or something when I created the user commandline.

To fix it, I used mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables on the db server so I could log in with phpMyAdmin. Using phpMyAdmin, I edited the user to change the password (via edit, not SQL to prevent shennanigans). Now I can log in like normal without using the "no security" option on my db server.